# Managing AWS Lambda Function Instances with code

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-functions, cloud

I am trying to figure out a way to create a rotating proxy service for web scraping using AWS Lambda. If I deploy a Lambda function which will be used to accept a web address, send the http request and then return the HTML/JSON etc.

Is there a way I can write another piece of code (maybe hosted on a VM) that can manage how many Lambda function instances have been deployed, create new instances, and stop instances that have been used after a certain time/number of requests? Ideally this could be some kind of service written with C# so if there is some kind of NUGET package that would be ideal.

I would also be interested to know if there is a library for managing the above using Azure functions as well (again ideally using C#).

(I am assuming that each Lambda function instance has a good chance of having a different public IP address.)

Thanks for your help!

So far, I have had a look on github and found a few examples of rotating proxies using python but I don't know enough about AWS to get any further.

Comment: Sounds like you should use fargate instead, you have very little control over lambda instances.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I don't know a lot about fargate - why would that be a better choice? And is there a way to manage container instances using C# code like I mentioned in my post?

Comment: Using fargate: yes. Using lambda: no. In both cases the language does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You have limited control over Lambda instances from an external system.

What could do is embedding a timeout control / reporting system inside the Lambda function, using the [get_remaining_time_in_millis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html) function (it gives you the time in milliseconds before the instance times out) and SNS messages.

Let's assume your scrapping function has a 3s timeout for the scrapped site to reply. You pass your URLs to lambda:

- if the remaining execution time is **more** than 4s, the lambda launches the scrap. At the end, it stores the data and [sends a SNS message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html) confirming if the scrap has been performed properly or failed,
- if the remaining execution time is **less** than 4s, the lambda does not launch the scrap, and directly returns a SNS message saying "not enough time to scrap".

Your external system reads the SNS messages received from Lambda, and marks the URL as "scrapped properly" / "failed" / "to retry". The only drawback, as you can not kill a specific lambda instance, is that you may relaunch several times the same lambda instance during the last 4 seconds before it times out. Therefore, if you go this route, it is better to use the maximum 15 minutes timeout allowed for Lambda functions, to minimize the wasted executions.

Just a side note: If the purpose of rotating lambda functions is just to get a new IP address, keep in mind that the IP you get from Lambda is a datacenter IP. All the addresses will be in same IP range based on the AWS region you use, and are easy flagged as scrapper as AWS discloses publicly this IPs. It might be better to keep your scrapping backend system simple, and only rotate the proxy using a residential IP provider.